# Django registration SMTPServerDisconnected error

Tags: django, authentication, django-registration

I use [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) for my project to manage user registration, login, etc. But When I sign up for an account I came across this problem:

`SMTPServerDisconnected`

For the record, I did configure email related settings in my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'                                                                                                                                           
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
```

Also I have all the templates needed and accessible. So this problem doesn't have anything to do with that.

More Error description:

After I click on the send activation email, it takes a long time before it finally give that  error.

Here is the traceback (not complete):

```
SMTPServerDisconnected at /accounts/register/

Connection unexpectedly closed

last trace back:

/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py in getreply

                    line = self.file.readline()

                except socket.error as e:

                    self.close()

                    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed: "

                                                 + str(e))

                if line == '':

                    self.close()

                    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")

    ...

                if self.debuglevel > 0:

                    print>>stderr, 'reply:', repr(line)

                resp.append(line[4:].strip())

                code = line[:3]

                # Check that the error code is syntactically correct.

                # Don't attempt to read a continuation line if it is broken.
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think at least one setting is incorrect. Port 587 is required for TLS [1]

`EMAIL_PORT = 587`

[1] http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: Half writing my answer and I saw a new answer slide in. Yes, It's this problem and I am gonna choose your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I figured this out. I post my solution here in case someone else get stuck here. The problem is the Gmail port. Use 587 and it worked.

I saw it here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9575

I wonder why some people can use 465 and some can't. It cost me a few hours to find out. Hope your guys won't!

EDIT: See h[ere](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17471) for more dicussion about use of port.

```
To use port 465, you need to call smtplib.SMTP_SSL(). Currently, it looks like Django only uses smtplib.SMTP().
```

Seems 587 is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, you might want to check https://github.com/bancek/django-smtp-ssl

Answer (score 1):

Django Gmail Confi   # settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True    # use port 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False    # use port 587
EMAIL_PORT = 465 # OR 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER =  os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =os.environ.get('USER_EMAIL_PASS')
```

helper.py  (function)

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
def send(sub=None,message=None,recipient=[]):
    # def send_mail(
                    # subject,
                    # message,
                    # from_email,
                    # recipient_list,
                    # fail_silently=False,
                    # auth_user=None,
                    # auth_password=None,
                    # connection=None,
                    # html_message=None):

    send_mail(subject='contact mail'
                       ,message='Test Mail'
                       ,from_email=EMAIL_HOST_USER
                       ,recipient_list=['mail_list']
                       ,fail_silently=False)
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not having any luck with the above answers, you may want to check to see if you have set your DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL in the settings.py

```
    # project/settings.py
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'                                                                                                                                           
    EMAIL_PORT = 465
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
```